# WebSecurity CreateUserAndAccount

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, security, asp.net-mvc-4

Im calling CreateUserAndAccount method giving String in username and password. But i get an exception saying that the hardcoded string is null. 
How can this being possible!?!
I-m missing something here?

Code: `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Admin", "Admin", null, false);`

SQLEXCEPTION: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserPwd', table 'servidb.dbo.User'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I changed table's name from UserProfile to User and Password column too. Could be here the mistake??

Regards.

ps: i dont know what else of the code to show. If need more info, please ask.

edit: Actually i did :

`WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("connectionString", "User", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);`

And i checked the DB and the table User was created with the column. My entity code is this one

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserPwd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using EF? If yes you might want to change the Autogeneratetables to false.

Comment: I am, also i would like to point out that is code first. Set the autocreate to false but still happening.

Comment: Can you try creating User separately and then using `CreateAccount` to create an account in the memebership table? See if that works.

Comment: Atm im trying to just save id and username and the pwd on mermbership. If that does not work, i will try that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Admin", "Admin", new {UserPwd = ""}, false)
```

The 3rd parameter represents an anonymous object that you can use to supply your `Required` fields so that your SQL gets all the non-null values it needs

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you changed those column names, WebSecurity knows itself what columns to use, it actually uses own generated tables, except for your table with usernames. Probably it's in your InitializeSimplemembership.cs if you are workin on Internet template.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection([here database username],
[here database password], [here YOUR talbe name containing user name column], 
[here user name column] , autoCreateTables: true);
```

So you create only one table with UserName column and that's all, the rest is created by WebSecurity in new tables.

Comment: thx for the answer. I edited the post. Resumen, the column UserPwd is created on Table User